# Hive remote postgres metastore

Tags: hadoop, hive, metastore, hive-metastore

I was doing multi-node setup using Apache distribution .I was able to complete hadoop installation successfully (Hadoop 2.7.3).
When I tried hive (Hive 2.3),its working without issues with the default metastore(derby).Then I changed the hive-site.xml to point to my external postgresDB
I gave host,username,password as per the tutorial .But when I ran the schemainit it is faliling as bellow ,still showing derby details  and initialization
is failing .Anybody faced the same issue ever?

```
bash-4.2$ /data/hive/bin/schematool  -initSchema  -dbType postgres --verbose
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Metastore connection URL:     jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true
Metastore Connection Driver :     org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
Metastore connection User:     APP
Starting metastore schema initialization to 2.3.0
Initialization script hive-schema-2.3.0.postgres.sql
Connecting to jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true
Connected to: Apache Derby (version 10.10.2.0 - (1582446))
Driver: Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver (version 10.10.2.0 - (1582446))
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
0: jdbc:derby:> !autocommit on
Autocommit status: true
0: jdbc:derby:> SET statement_timeout = 0
Error: Syntax error: Encountered "statement_timeout" at line 1, column 5. (state=42X01,code=30000)
Closing: 0: jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Schema initialization FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent !!
Underlying cause: java.io.IOException : Schema script failed, errorcode 2
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Schema initialization FAILED! Metastore state would be inconsistent !!
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:590)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:563)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.main(HiveSchemaTool.java:1145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Schema script failed, errorcode 2
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.runBeeLine(HiveSchemaTool.java:980)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.runBeeLine(HiveSchemaTool.java:959)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:586)
    ... 8 more
*** schemaTool failed ***
```

Comment: hi @anoop, did you find any solution ?